# Why does GCC on x86-64 insert a NOP inside of a function?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, no-op

Given the following C function:

```
void go(char *data) {
    char name[64];
    strcpy(name, data);
}
```

GCC 5 and 6 on x86-64 compile (plain `gcc -c -g -o` followed by `objdump`) this to:

```
0000000000000000 <go>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp
   8:   48 89 7d b8             mov    %rdi,-0x48(%rbp)
   c:   48 8b 55 b8             mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rdx
  10:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
  14:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  17:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  1a:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1f <go+0x1f>
  1f:   90                      nop
  20:   c9                      leaveq 
  21:   c3                      retq
```

Is there any reason for GCC to insert the `90`/`nop` at `1f` or is that just a side-effect that might happen when no optimizations are turned on?

*Note: This question is different from most others because it asks about `nop` inside a function body, not an external padding.*

*Compiler versions tested: GCC Debian 5.3.1-14 (5.3.1) and Debian 6-20160313-1 (6.0.0)*

Comment: NOPs are often used for timing reasons. Normally it is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Why would you be concerned with *timing* in the above ?

Comment: May have to do with pipelining and wait-states?

Comment: @BrianAgnew The compiler can't really tell if that piece of code is time-critical or not, and since it hasn't be told to disable optimizations it does the best it can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does GCC pad functions with NOPs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912464/why-does-gcc-pad-functions-with-nops)

Comment: ...inserted for breakpoints? Debuggers don't need you to insert needless nops for breakpoints...

Comment: This is at **`-O0` only**.  There's no timing reason, and no pipelining reason.  It doesn't help anything.

Comment: @BrianAgnew: This is **not a duplicate** of that question.  Putting a `nop` inside the function body, rather than as padding between functions, is new in gcc5.  Also note that this `nop` is there as a `nop` in the `gcc -S` asm output, not as a `.p2align` directive.

Comment: This is weird. GCC 5.3.0 on OSX (x86-64) doesn't insert the `nop`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's weird, I'd never noticed stray `nop`s in the asm output at `-O0` before.  (Probably because I don't waste my time looking at un-optimized compiler output).

Usually `nop`s inside functions are to align branch targets, including function entry points like in [the question Brian linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912464/why-does-gcc-pad-functions-with-nops).  (Also see `-falign-loops` [in the gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), which is on by default at optimization levels other than `-Os`).

---

In this case, the `nop` is part of the compiler noise for a bare empty function:

```
void go(void) {
    //char name[64];
    //strcpy(name, data);
}
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    nop                     # only present for gcc5, not gcc 4.9.3
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

[See that code in the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-O0++-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm',source:'%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0Avoid+go(void)+%7B%0A++++//char+name%5B64%5D%3B%0A++++//strcpy(name,+data)%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) so you can check the asm for other compiler versions and compile options.

(Not technically noise, but `-O0` enables `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, and at -O0 even empty functions set up and tear down a stack frame.)

---

Of course, that `nop` is not present at any non-zero optimization level.  **There's no debugging or performance advantage to that `nop` in the code in the question.**  (See the performance guide links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, esp. [Agner Fog's microarchitecture guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) to learn about what makes code fast on current CPUs.)

**My guess is that it's purely an artifact of gcc internals**.  This `nop` is there as a `nop` in the `gcc -S` asm output, not as a `.p2align` directive.  gcc itself doesn't count machine code bytes, it just uses alignment directives at certain points to align important branch targets.  Only the assembler knows how big a `nop` is actually needed to reach the given alignment.

The default `-O0` tells gcc that you want it to compile fast and *not* make good code.  This means the asm output tells you more about gcc internals than other `-O` levels, and very little about how to optimize or anything else.

If you're trying to learn asm, it's more interesting to look at the code at `-Og`, for example (optimize for debugging).

If you're trying to see how well gcc or clang do at making code, you should look at `-O3 -march=native` (or `-O2 -mtune=intel`, or whatever settings you build your project with).  Puzzling out the optimizations made at `-O3` is a good way to learn some asm tricks, though.  `-fno-tree-vectorize` is handy if you want to see a non-vectorized version of something fully optimized other than that.

Comment: Good answer. Very interesting